# "Visit the help center", instead of going to meta.stackoverflow.com/help goes to stackoverflow.com/help

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, help-center

"Visit the help center", which appears when creating a new question, instead of going to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help goes to https://stackoverflow.com/help.

Is this intended? Where am I supposed to go to get help writing on meta?

I understand there is a significant overlap between all sites, like avoid dupes, have good spelling/grammar, etc. But the guidelines for what is on-topic and off topic are different between the sites.

I am already capable of writing with quality on SO, but on Meta I currently lack a positive question record.

Answer (score 1):

The help center is pretty much the same information no matter what site you're looking at. Only a few of the pages change from site to site, and the "What's Meta?" help center article is always available in every help center. It's even explicitly linked in the menu directly below the Help Center link if you're viewing a meta site, since that's a highly relevant article for anyone who lands on Meta.

There's no reason to maintain a separate help center for Meta since it would just contain all the same information.

Comment: Would there be a difference between the info for "what kinds of questions are appropriate on SE Meta" and "what kinds of questions are appropriate on SO Meta"?